# SSIS build artifact generated from Azure Devops Classic Pipeline not reflecting latest changes

Tags: azure-devops, ssis, visual-studio-2022

Build Pipeline : Classic

SSIS Compiler : Visual Studio\2022\Enterprise - devenv.exe (Custom)

SSIS Build Task Version : 2*

When running a classic build pipeline in azure devops, can see latest commitID and appropriate branch been referred in git checkout logs whereas the ispac (Artifact) file generated post build, not reflecting the latest code changes. Any pointer to explore resolving this issue.

The changes were only a new .dtsx file added.

Comment: Can you please share more information on how you observed the build artifact was not reflecting the latest changes in your code? Please some screenshots to help understand the issue and let us know how the artifact was generated during the build. Besides, would you also provide the [debug logs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/troubleshooting/review-logs?view=azure-devops) of all concerned steps?

Comment: Thanks for input. have updated the visual studio as input received from microsoft support. Posted here as they were clueless upon seeing logs. Unable to provide logs here. sorry & thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Updating latest version of Visual Studio 2022 in the agent machine, helped to resolve this strange issue.